# How to click save as button when downloading a file?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

When clicking on a link for example:

```
<a href="1.txt">Download</a>
```

a save as window will pop up. Is it possible to use JavaScript to click buttons on the window? Or, can a call back function be set when the button is clicked?

Comment: If you have to worry about it, you are doing it wrong! You shouldn't really try to intercept the way browser prompts the user for download (also it wont let you :))

Comment: JavaScript in an HTML document cannot do anything outside the document. Particularly, it cannot click random buttons in the browser GUI. You cannot force a user to store anything in his hard disc. If if was possible, your HD would already be full of junk and malware.

Comment: It's definitely bad user experience if any software decided where to save my files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expand on my comment here and put it as an answer.

In general you should not have anything to do with the way your Browser handles the download. In your case (correct me if I am wrong), you want to click on the "Save" button on the "Save as" window -- which is something your browser wont allow you to do (In other words, there are no APIs for them). Just imagine, if you could do that you can trigger millions of such saves when the user visits your site. That'd be a very bad example of a browser.

In general, send a header from the server side:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="abc.xyz"
```

That should be enough to trigger a download. You shouldn't worry about the way it is handled by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the file to download and not open automatically right? Look at this explanation of how to do this using PHP
http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm

if you aren't using php - tell me which language you are using and I'll try and figure out the code.